# Removing external app migration in Django south

Tags: django, django-models, django-south, database-migration

When an external Django app is no longer being used (i.e. removed from `INSTALLED_APPS`), what is the proper way to create a migration that deletes all its tables from the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is to migrate the app to the `zero` migration.

`./manage.py migrate <app_name> zero`

This will apply all reverse migrations.

If this isn't sufficient for some reason, write your own schema(/data) migration(s).

Comment: Right, I didn't think of this. New environments will never see the external app (since it's removed completely) and thus will never need to run the reverse migration to zero. Existing environments can run the zero migration as you mentioned as a one-time thing. This is good enough, thanks!